# Cannot map image <src> to object located in parent scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to bind image `<src>` with an object created inside of a scope of a `$parent` controller. This is the code i have so far:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <img style="max-height: 250px; max-width: 200px;" src="app/test_resources/guest.png" id="sectionImg"></img>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%;height: 30px; display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;" value="Load Image" onclick="$('#loadFileImg').click();" />
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" id="loadFileImg" ng-required="true" ng-model="$parent.section.img" onchange="readURL(this);" style="display:none;" name="file"/>
</div>
```

And here is the function i use to load image from file system and bind it to `<src>` of `#sectionImg`

```
<script>

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#sectionImg')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200)
                .css({'margin-bottom':'10px'});
            console.log($('#sectionImg').attr('src'));
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}      

</script>
```

This is what logic designed for creating new section inside of my controller looks like:

```
$scope.section = {};

$scope.createSection = function(){         
     console.log("New section details:"+angular.toJson($scope.section));
     console.log("Image: "+angular.toJson($scope.section.img));
}
```

Now $scope.section should also contain img property ( in other words `$scope.section.img` should be the path of the image loaded from file) but for some reason `$scope.section` has everything EXCEPT the path of the loaded img, i guess `ng-model="$parent.section.img"` does not work.

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

**NOTE:** *The rest of the form maps  to $parent.section.description and $parent.section.name, and that works fine, so $parent is not the problem before anyone suggests that.*

Comment: Sorry i am not sure i understand the question

Comment: Well image i am trying to load is located here : `webapp/app/resources` and my welcome page `webapp/views/main.html` . I am sorry but i dont see how that is relevent, could you please explain it to me?